# Ambiguous reference error?

Tags: c#

After I detected the largest contour by using `canny` filter I want now to extract only what exists inside it.

```
Rectangle rect = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contours[largest_contour_index]);            
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
{
    g.DrawImage(imageInput, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
                rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

imageBox2.Image = imageInput;
```

I get this error:

> Error CS0104 'Graphics' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Drawing.Graphics' and 'UnityEngine.Graphics'

Any ideas how it can be fixed?

Comment: Please change the title to reflect the actual question

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct; an additional technique that is useful in these situations is to make an aliasing directive at the top of your file:

```
using SDGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics;
```

And now you can say `SDGraphics` where you would normally say `Graphics`, and it will not be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is actually quite to the point. Change Graphics to System.Drawing.Graphics to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Or, possibly, to `UnityEngine.Graphics`. It's a little ambiguous. Ha. Ha.

Comment: Well, since I’m not a compiler, I could read the rest of the line ;)